# Declaring resources in multiple files in Serverless framework

Tags: serverless-framework

Is there any way to split the resource definitions in serverless framework into multiple files? Something like:

```
resources:
  - ${resources/base.yml}
  - ${resources/foo.yml}
```

I have been trying multiple combinations but I keep getting errors about references not being found.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Even though **dashmug**'s answer is correct, I found that the way I was trying to make it work was quite close to a valid solution too. As explained in [this github comment](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2828#issuecomment-333305670) it is possible to reference other files in the resources section:

```
resources:
   - ${file(resources/first-cf-resources.yml)}
   - ${file(resources/second-cf-resources.yml)}
```

Provided that each those files defines a "Resources" key of its own, like:

```
---
Resources:
  MyCFResource:
    Type:.....
```

What I didn't manage is to have a mixed approach such as:

```
resources:
  - ${file(resources/first-cf-resources.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/second-cf-resources.yml)}
  SomeResource:
    Type: ...
```

So I just have a resources/base.yml for that instead.

Comment: PSA: This will fail horribly if you have an empty .yml file included this way (where empty means having the "Resources:" header and nothing else.

Comment: "horribly" is right. It took me hours to figure this out - kept having `instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource` errors for no apparent reason with no errors shown - a  file with just "Resources" (I had commented stuff out) will silently corrupt your setup. Thank you @Techrocket9

Comment: The mixed approach is possible, but requires precise (and seemingly inconsistent) indentation (needing 4 spaces where 2 is expected). The error messages that result of incorrect indentation will not be helpful either.

Comment: @Techrocket9: The horrible failing part can be avoided by using a fallback 'empty string'; example `- ${file(resources/NonExistingFile-cf-resources.yml), ''}`

Answer (score 17):

I can't comment but I'd like to extend Jesuspc's answer.

There is a way to achieve that 'mixed' approach, in serverless.yml:

```
resources:
  - ${file(resources/first-cf-resources.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/second-cf-resources.yml)}
  - Resources:
      SomeResource:
        Type: ...
```

In this case files `first-cf-resources.yml` and `second-cf-resources.yml` must have the next structure:

```
Resources:
  SomeResourceA:
    ...
  AnotherResourceB:
    ...
```

Comment: @DeusProx `first-cf-resources.yml` should also start from `Resources:`

Comment: I always do "resources: Resources: ..." and reference them like "- ${file(./resourcefile.yml):resources}", but it only works when just using references.

Answer (score 4):

Take note that the `resources` property has to be an object containing a `Resources` property, **NOT** an array of resources like what you wanted in your code snippet.

So, to use external file references, you can do something like...

```
resources
    Resources:
        UsersTable: ${file(../resources/base.yml):UsersTable}
        FooTable: ${file(../resources/foo.yml):FooTable}
```

Reference: [Reference variables in other files](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#reference-variables-in-other-files)